# Xamarin.Forms how to add app rating on Android and iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Which is the best/simplest option to add app rating on a Xamarin.Forms application, the default stars form directly connected to the Play Store or App Store?

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin

Comment: @Jason yeah, but this opens the url of the app in the store in the app, like a web view, I want to be shown the form directly in the app

Comment: read the "Request Review" section

Comment: @Jason the "Request Review" is the same for Android and iOS?

Comment: the docs clearly say "UWP and iOS"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**: I've created an nuget package for this, you can download from [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.XamarinAppRating/) or check the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/FabriBertani/Plugin.XamarinAppRating).

On Android you must open the PlayStore in order to rate the app, on iOS you can do it inside the app, but only from iOS 10 onwards.

You must implement native methods and use it via dependecy service.

**Interface**

```
public interface IAppRating
{
    void RateApp();
}
```

**Android**

```
public class AppRatiing : IAppRating
{
    public void RateApp()
    {
        var activity = Android.App.Application.Context;
        var url = $"market://details?id={(activity as Context)?.PackageName}";

        try
        {
            activity.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo("com.android.vending", PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));

            activity.StartActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex)
        {
            // this won't happen. But catching just in case the user has downloaded the app without having Google Play installed.

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException)
        {
            // if Google Play fails to load, open the App link on the browser 

            var playStoreUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourapplicationpackagename"; //Add here the url of your application on the store

            var browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(playStoreUrl));
            browserIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ResetTaskIfNeeded);

            activity.StartActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS**

```
public class AppRating : IAppRating
{
    public void RateApp()
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 3))
            SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview();
        else
        {
            var storeUrl = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/YourAppId";
            var url = storeUrl + "?action=write-review";

            try
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(url));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Here you could show an alert to the user telling that App Store was unable to launch

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @FabriBertrani, thanks a lot man, one last doubt, how I do to control and call the RateApp() method only when the user has been using the app for a while? Is there a way that the plugin does it automatically?

Comment: I just use a counter on the app start and storage that counter, when the counter reachs certain number it shows a dialog to the users asking them if they want to rate the app (you need to do this because is less invasive and Apple can penalize you)

Comment: Hello @FabriBertani, I used your code and it works good for me on iPhone Simulator, however when I published the app the rating popup did not appear even if the counter is reached, any idea? Please advise. IOS used is 13.2

Comment: Hello @FadlAssaad, I've tested on iOS 13.2 and works fine, maybe you should check for other issues that might be happening on release mode. Cheers

Comment: If anyone has `using System` in their file, note that you will need to fully qualify the `Uri` class: `Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url)`

Answer (score 1):

On Android (tested in `9.0`) I have to add this flag at [FabriBertani´s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55923522/3559353) solution:

```cs
activity.StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Store Review Nuget plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.StoreReview/) has been updated to v3 recently thanks to the new (August 2020) Android native Play Core library so that it displays an In-App Review on both iOS & Android using just one line of code:

```
await CrossStoreReview.Current.RequestReview(false);
```

So now, you don't have to worry about opening the url of the app in the external store or a web view, it will be shown directly in the app. You can see more details on [this Microsoft Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-in-app-reviews/)

Just remember to add the necessary code in the proguard file mentioned in the [README of the Nuget's GitHub repository](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin)

Comment: Hi Saamer, I've tried to install **Plugin.StoreReview** for Android and get the following error: `Unable to resolve dependencies. 'PlayCore 1.10.0' is not compatible with 'Plugin.StoreReview 5.0.1 constraint: PlayCore (>= 1.10.2-rc2)'`. When I try to install PlayCore from Nuget the max version I can find is `1.10.0` though, so I'm stuck. How can I install the plugin correctly?

Comment: @jho is there a pre-release version that is newer?

Comment: Not sure of your question there Saamer, but I installed an earlier version 3.x and it sort of works (saw the dialogue flash up once, but it never appeared after that.) But isn't it odd that v5.0.1 depends on what appears to be a release candidate PlayCore lib that is not on nuget. Shouldn't all dependencies be available with full release versions used?